# How to check that a known Windows Vulnerability has been patched?

Tags: windows, pci-dss, vulnerabilities, security

Is there a way in Windows to check that say Security Bulletin `MS**-***` or `CVE-****-*****` has been patched? e.g. something akin to RedHat's `rpm -q --changelog service`

Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running [SystemInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx) against your server (`systeminfo /s $SERVER`) should also list installed hotfixes.

```
Hotfix(s): 333 Hotfix(s) Installed.
[161]: IDNMitigationAPIs - Update
[162]: NLSDownlevelMapping - Update
[163]: KB929399
[164]: KB952069_WM9
[165]: KB968816_WM9
[166]: KB973540_WM9L
[167]: KB936782_WMP11
```

Comment: that did it. Thanx

Comment: The coolness and simplicity of this cannot be understated. : )

Answer (score 4):

WMIC can list installed hotfixes:

```
C:\>wmic qfe get hotfixid, installedon
HotFixID   InstalledOn
KB2605658  11/30/2011
KB2608610  9/1/2011
KB2608612  9/26/2011
KB2614194  9/26/2011
...(more)...
```

It can also **search** for a specific hotfix. Here I show two searches - one successful, one unsuccessful:

```
C:\>wmic qfe where (hotfixid = 'KB2608610') get hotfixid, installedon
HotFixID   InstalledOn
KB2608610  9/1/2011

C:\>wmic qfe where (hotfixid = 'nosuch') get hotfixid, installedon
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Answer (score 3):

I run [PSinfo -h](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550) against the server to show installed hotfixes.

Comment: nice, but it doesn't list any hotfixes

Comment: It should look something like this, if I knew anything about formatting this stuff properly. Installed     HotFix
2007-11-17    Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Hotfix (KB928366)
2008-10-27    Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Hotfix (KB947742)
2007-05-25    Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1 (KB867460)
2004-07-17    Microsoft Data Access Components KB870669

Comment: I understand. The link you provided has a pretty good example of the output also. It just doesn't list anything for me. I don't suppose it has anything to do w/ me using SP1?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am seeing some feedback on the SP displaying incorrectly on R2.  An alternate solution you might try is a Powershell script that will pull the hotfixes for you.

Comment: Will do. Thanx Mitch

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative if you can't use pstools and find yourself stuck with native Winder tools:

```
reg query hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall /s | findstr "KB[0-9].*" > %TEMP%\Installed.txt & notepad %TEMP%\Installed.txt
```

Comment: I like that better. I prefer the cli myself. Although, there still is nothing listed when I run this.

Answer (score 1):

Also for checking vulnerabilities on subsystems that you might not know about on the system, [the Microsoft Baseline Security Analayzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923) is a fairly useful tool. It's not always the ones you know about that get you, sometimes there are oddball things installed that aren't scanned or serviced by WSUS or Microsoft Update that can remain unpatched or unmitigated for the life of the system.

Comment: I'll check it out thanx